# Why doesn't the density of water add up?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, density

If the density of hydrogen is 0.09 g/ml and the density of oxygen is 1.429 g/ml, how is it that the density of water is 1 g/ml?

Comment: Note that the unit for the density of the gases is not correct. At normal temperature and pressure, the density of hydrogen is 0.09 g/l (not 0.09 g/ml), and the density of oxygen is 1.429 g/l (not 1.429 g/ml).

Comment: Any "mixture", with a chemical reaction or without, can only be expected to have the "average" density if the particles in both are of similar form and size and there is no enthalpic interaction. So really *never* with a chemical reaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The densities of hydrogen and oxygen actually do approximately add up to the density of water if you use a state (temperature and pressure) where all three compounds may be considered to be an **ideal gas** (whereas at normal temperature and pressure, hydrogen and oxygen are gases, but water is liquid).

For example, at a temperature of $T=200\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and a pressure of $p=1\ \mathrm{bar}$, all three compounds are gases with the following densities:

$$\begin{align}
\rho(\ce{H2})&=0.05122\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}\\  
\rho(\ce{O2})&=0.81329\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}\\  
\rho(\ce{H2O})&=0.46031\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}
\end{align}$$

You also have to take into account that hydrogen molecules ($\ce{H2}$) consist of two hydrogen atoms, oxygen molecules ($\ce{O2}$) consist of two oxygen atoms, and water molecules ($\ce{H2O}$) consist of two hydrogen atoms and one water atom:

$$\ce{H2 + 1/2O2 -> H2O}$$

Thus, the density of water can be estimated as

$$\begin{align}
\rho(\ce{H2O})&\approx\rho(\ce{H2})+\frac12\rho(\ce{O2})\\[6pt]
&=0.05122\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}+\frac12\times0.81329\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}\\[6pt]
&=0.45787\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}
\end{align}$$

which is quite close to the real value of $\rho(\ce{H2O})=0.46031\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}$.

---

**Explanation**

Density $\rho$ is defined as
$$\rho=\frac{m}{V}$$
where
$m$ is mass, and
$V$ is volume.

The mass of a pure sample is given as
$$m=n\cdot M$$
where
$n$ is amount of substance, and
$M$ is molar mass.

The volume of a gas can be estimated using the ideal gas law as follows.
$$\begin{align}
p\cdot V&=n\cdot R\cdot T\\[6pt]
V&=\frac{n\cdot R\cdot T}{p}
\end{align}$$
where
$T$ is temperature,
$p$ is pressure, and
$R=8.314462618\ \mathrm{J\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1}}$<sup>[[source](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?r)]</sup> is the molar gas constant.

Therefore, the density of an ideal gas at a given temperature and pressure only depends on the molar mass of the gas.
$$\begin{align}
\rho&=\frac{m}{V}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{n\cdot M}{\frac{n\cdot R\cdot T}{p}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{M\cdot p}{R\cdot T}
\end{align}$$

And the molar mass of water can be calculated from the molar mass of hydrogen and oxygen as
$$M(\ce{H2O})=M(\ce{H2})+\frac12M(\ce{O2})$$

Comment: This certainly does not help to correct the OPs obvious, grave misunderstanding.

Comment: @karl and, worse, it confuses the key issue by making everything about gas-phase density which is a *completely* different matter than liquid or solid density.

Comment: Actually, this is a wonderful method. I am tempted to ask, does this work for all gaseous compounds? or are there some known exceptions?